# Change from old style numbers to lining numbers in lineno's linenumbers environment

Tags: fontspec, line-numbering, oldstylenums

I am using old style numbers in my document, but I prefer lining numbers in my line numbering environments (`lineno`'s `\linenumbers` environment). How can I enforce this (without changing to another font)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lineno}
    \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
    \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\scriptsize\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers}
\noindent Continual delighted\linelabel{1stword} as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing\linelabel{2ndword} it thoughts. View busy dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced\linelabel{3rdword} see middletons nor preference.
\end{linenumbers}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent I like the words I find in line \lineref{1stword}, \lineref{2ndword}, and \lineref{3rdword}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **Hint:** define a custom environment wrapping the `linenumbers` and changing font to new, with desired numbers style.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not savvy enough to be able to know what to do with hints like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To just change the numbers, use the `fontspec` command `\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining, Monospaced}}` (see section 10.3 of the [`fontspec` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontspec)). (You probably don’t even need to specify `Monospaced`, but it doesn’t hurt to specify it.) `\normalfont` and `\rmfamily` aren’t necessary either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lineno}
    \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
    \renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\scriptsize\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining, Monospaced}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers}
\noindent Continual delighted\linelabel{1stword} as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. 
Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold
four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it
bringing\linelabel{2ndword} it thoughts. View busy dine oh in knew if even. Boy these
along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put 
introduced\linelabel{3rdword} see middletons nor preference.
\end{linenumbers}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent I like the words I find in line \lineref{1stword}, \lineref{2ndword}, and
\lineref{3rdword}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Works. Answer accepted. Is there a convention of having monospaced characters in line numbers?

Comment: @Sverre Not that I know of; however, there is sort of a convention to use monospaced numbers/digits in tables (just so that everything vertically aligns neatly), and the line numbers seemed to be table-like enough for me. Note that I didn’t check if monospaced numbers would’ve been used at any rate (i.e. without me specifying), it actually seems to be like that. One way or the other, I’d expect this to look better, especially once you get into the double- and triple-digit ranges.

Answer (score 6):

For Type 1 font (pdflatex) users the following would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lineno}

\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}\scriptsize\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers}
\noindent Continual delighted\linelabel{1stword} as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing\linelabel{2ndword} it thoughts. View busy dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced\linelabel{3rdword} see middletons nor preference.
\end{linenumbers}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent I like the words I find in line \lineref{1stword}, \lineref{2ndword}, and \lineref{3rdword}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: And for ``fontspec`` users? :)

Comment: @Sverre I am a LaTeX oldtimer, I don't have the slightest clue how that newfangled stuff works ;-)

Comment: @Sverre I tested with `lmr` instead of that Linux font and it works!

Comment: @Sigur: I don't understand.

Comment: @Sverre, your code works very well just using `\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\fontfamily{lmr}\scriptsize\selectfont}`. So you can use `fontspec`.

Comment: I see. It's implicit (now explicit) in my question that I don't want to change the font altogether for my lining numbers.

Comment: @Sverre, I just changed to `lmr` since with the @mapf suggestion I got the warning *No file EU2LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd. on input line 9.*. So I don't have that font but if you have it I believe that it will work.

Comment: @Sigur: But what you're doing with your ``lmr`` call is to switch from the Linux Libertine font to the Latin Modern Roman (=lmr) font.

Comment: Yes, but I guess that you don't need to change the font. The @mafp answer is not working to you?

Comment: @mafp Whether this works or not, this definitely is not the way you’re supposed to do things when using `fontspec` (and thus Xe/LuaLaTeX).

Comment: @doncherry Did I somehow suggested that?!

Comment: @mafp I guess not explicitly, even though the question does call for `fontspec`. Pehaps you could complement the code in your answer to a full MWE and make it really obvious that this is a pdfLaTeX solution? Then we’d actually have covered all of our bases.